# Graph API call returns "Invalid token: \" https:\". An ID has already been specified.",

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to run this command to send requests to the three friends I specified:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com//apprequests?ids=1000020,10000498163,63027&message='This is the message use this app man&data='This is some data or whateverz'&AAACEdEose0cBABlELWtsbtarJjOK2VqfZAuvlizieN1BtsB3izXhuHfwZDZD&method=post
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 "error": {
    "message": "Invalid token: \" https:\".  An ID has already been specified.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it wrong, that's not the way you send app requests. Instead, you are actually accessing user's app requests (requests made by his friends).
To send app requests, you've to use this URL: `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?`

So in your case if you want send requests to some specific user ids, then it will be like:

`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=YOURAPPID&message=Your%20message!&to=100005354380146,100005240530237&redirect_uri=http://localhost/MyExample.aspx`

And if you ignore the `to` parameter, then a full dialog with all his friend listed will be displayed from which the user can choose the targeted friends.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including a user ID (or 'me') between 'facebook.com' and 'apprequests'?

If so, that first part of the path is the object ID you're acting on, so the extra 'ids' parameter is invalid. if not, omit one of the forward slashes.

It also appears from the text of the error that you're doing something like
`$facebook->api('https://www.facebook....')` (to use a PHP example) or somehow making a request to the API with the path to the API method included twice

( see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests )

Comment: Thanks! Each of those ID's is one of my friends I want to send a message to. I removed the first slash and tried tried it with only one friend ID and now I get this error (ironically) (#100) Specifying multiple ids with a post method is not supported". I'm not sure what you mean about me including the path twice...

Comment: The example i gave was what people sometimes do which results in a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/https://graph.facebook.com/something` - OK, so you've found the problem you were trying to post multiple app-> user requests in a single call which isn't supported, you'll need to use a batch request or loop through the IDs you're sending to